# Regex for matching a character later in the string if a certain character is present before

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have the following string

```
['json.key']
```

I want a regex pattern that will match the entire string because it contains the matching closing `']` to the opening `['`.

But sometimes the `['` and `']` don't have to exist, and it should be okay too.

```
jsonKey
```

But I don't want strings like these to match

```
['jsonKey
jsonKey']
```

Because they are missing the matching `['` and `']`.

The current regex pattern I have for this is

```
(\[')?[\w-]+('])?
```

But this doesn't quite work because it lets the two last cases pass.

I need a regex pattern for Java and JavaScript code. But they are separate modules, it could be different patterns.

Comment: What is your regex tool?

Comment: It depends on the regex tool you use. With ECMAscript it's slightly clunky but this works: https://regex101.com/r/bcIAoW/1

Comment: I need the regex in Java and JavaScript. Sorry, I forgot that detail.

Comment: Java _and_ JavaScript??

Comment: @code, it could be different patterns. But I need a pattern for Java and JavaScript :/

Answer (score 4):

In Java or Javascript you can use alternation and look arounds like this:

```bash
(?<!\S)(?:\['[\w-]+']|[\w-]+)(?!\S)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPdDAM/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\S)`: Assert that previous char is not a non-whitespace
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\['[\w-]+']`: Match `['<1+ word char>']`
  - `|`: OR
  - `[\w-]+`: Match 1+ of word char or hyphen
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(?!\S)`: Assert that next char is not a non-whitespace

Comment: I am not sure if the dot is really there since OP posted `... [\w-]+ ...` (apparently working for the first example string)

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird, for including dot we can add `.` inside the character class